# Как заполнить форму данными из словаря? Python, Flask

Tags: python, flask

Моя проблема в том, что форма у меня динамическая:

```
class CollectionRequestParamForm(Form):
    param_human_name = StringField(validators=[DataRequired()])
    param_request_name = StringField()


class CollectionRequestParamCombinedForm(FlaskForm):
    params = FieldList(FormField(CollectionRequestParamForm), min_entries=1)
    submit = SubmitField('Submit')
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

После того, как пользователь отправил форму, в коллекцию (использую MongoDB) падает примерно такой словарь:

```
example_form = {
    'Имя': 'name',
    'Возраст': 'age'
}
```

Если этого потребует задача, то, конечно, могу изменить структуру на такую:

```
example_form = [
    {'param_human_name': 'Имя', 'param_request_name': 'name'},
    {'param_human_name': 'Возраст', 'param_request_name': 'age'},
]
```

Или другую, если нужно.

Допустим, пользователь уже заполнял данную форму. При открытии этой формы он должен видеть уже заполненную ранее форму:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но как мне ее заполнить в процессе обработки запроса? Я пробовал так:

```
i = 0
for key, value in example_form.items():
    collection_request_params_form.params.data[i]['param_human_name'] = key
    collection_request_params_form.params.data[i]['param_request_name'] = value
    ## Или так...
    collection_request_params_form.data['params'][i]['param_human_name'] = key
    collection_request_params_form.data['params'][i]['param_request_name'] = value
    i += 1
```

Но все это либо приводило к ошибкам, либо просто не работало.

Как же мне заполнить мою форму данными из словаря?

Answer (score 0):

Друзья, я пришел к такому решению:
Данные, введенные пользователем храню так:

```
request_params_list = [
    {'param_human_name': 'Имя', 'param_request_name': 'name'},
    {'param_human_name': 'Возраст', 'param_request_name': 'age'},
]
```

В представлении проверяю, была ли заполнена форма ранее (если да - то форму надо заполнить данными из словаря). Если метод запроса POST, то значит идет попытка изменить данные и грузить данные из словаря не нужно.

```
request_params_list = []
if 'request_params_list' in _collection and request.method != 'POST':
    request_params_list = _collection['request_params_list']
    for i in range(1, len(request_params_list)):
        collection_request_params_form.params.append_entry()
```

`_collection` - коллекция MongoDB

`params.append_entry()` - метод, найденный в документации. Добавляет в форму `CollectionRequestParamCombinedForm` столько `CollectionRequestParamForm` (строк формы), сколько будет вызван.

В шаблоне:

```
<form method="POST">
   <div class="request_params" data-toggle="request-params-fieldset"
      id="request-params-fieldset">
      <!--CollectionRequestParamForm fields-->
      {% for param in rp_form.params %}
        {% if request_params_list %}
            {% set param_human_name_value = request_params_list[loop.index0]['param_human_name'] %}
            {% set param_request_name_value = request_params_list[loop.index0]['param_request_name'] %}
        {% else %}
            {% set param_human_name_value = param.data.param_human_name or '' %}
            {% set param_request_name_value = param.data.param_request_name or '' %}
      {% endif %}
      <div class="row" data-toggle="request-params-fieldset-entry">
         <div class="col-3">
            {{ param.param_human_name(class="form-control", placeholder="Название (Имя пользователя)", value=param_human_name_value) }}
         </div>
         <div class="col-3">
            {{ param.param_request_name(class="form-control", placeholder="Параметр в запросе (u_name)", value=param_request_name_value) }}
         </div>
         <div>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger"
               data-toggle="request-params-fieldset-remove-row"
               id="request-params-row-{{ loop.index0 }}-remove"><i
               class="fa fa-times"
               aria-hidden="true"></i>
            </button>
         </div>
         <br>
         <br>
      </div>
      {% endfor %}
      <!--End CollectionRequestParamForm fields-->
      <!--Row for 'add new field' button-->
      <div class="row">
         <div class="col">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary"
               data-toggle="request-params-fieldset-add-row"
               data-target="#request-params-fieldset">Добавить еще
            </button>
            <br>
            <br>
         </div>
      </div>
      <!--End row for 'add new field' button-->
   </div>
   {{ rp_form.hidden_tag() }}
   {{ rp_form.csrf_token }}
   {{ rp_form.submit(class="btn btn-primary") }}
</form>
```

Шаблон комментировать не стану особо. Все вроде ясно - предаем список `request_params_list` и элементы этого списка растаскиваем по `value` input'ов